# Is there a quick way to extract values from a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

Assume there is a list that includes a numpy array such as

```
import numpy as np 
output = [np.array([[[5.21]],
                    [[2.22]],
                    [[1.10]],
                    [[3.76]]], dtype=np.float32)]
```

Is there any quick way to extract values from this output list such as

```
result = [5.21, 2.22, 1.10, 3.76]
```

many thanks

Comment: `list(output[0][0:,0].flatten())`

Comment: Think in steps.  First get the array out of the list.  Then convert the array to 1d.  Finally use `tolist` to get a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Try this

```
result = output[0].reshape(1,-1).flatten().tolist()
```